# Comma Separated Type Declaration Fatal Error "=" expected but "," found Free Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am learning Pascal using Free Pascal and VS Code. A compilation error occurs from a simple type declaration. I have looked at tutorials and books and the syntax seems good. If I remove "days," making it a single declaration it works fine. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
program Test;

uses crt;

type
days, age = integer; {Fatal: Syntax error, "=" expected but "," found}

var
myAge: age;

begin
   myAge := 5;
   writeln(myAge);
end.
```

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is wrong, see the syntax diagram at the beginning of [the Free Pascal Language Reference, Chapter 3 *Types*](https://freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/refch3.html#x24-230003):

> [image: Syntax Diagram for Free Pascal Type declaration blocks]

and [Chapter 3.8 *Type aliases*](https://freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/refse19.html#x49-690003.8):

> [image: Syntax Diagram for a Free Pascal type alias declaration]

As you can see, the syntax for a Free Pascal *type alias* in a `Type` block is:

1. A new *identifier* followed by
2. `=` (equals sign) followed by
3. the keyword `type` (optional, to declare a *new type* instead of an alias)
4. the identifier of an existing *type* followed by
5. `;` (semicolon)

So, the correct way to express what you want would be something like this:

```pascal
program Test;

uses crt;

type
   days = integer;
   age = integer;

var
   myAge: age;

begin
   myAge := 5;
   writeln(myAge);
end.
```

> I have looked at tutorials and books and the syntax seems good.

Well, as you can see from the documentation of the language you are writing in, it isn't.

> What am I missing?

You probably did not look at [the documentation](https://freepascal.org/docs.html) of [Free Pascal](https://freepascal.org/) but some other language.

Comment: Unfortunately I was following https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/ and it specifies that it's based on Free Pascal. The comma separated syntax was copied from there. I guess it's trash.